# Sylvester's Quote on Determinants

Tags: mathematics, quote, linear-algebra

What does the following quote by Sylvester mean?

> "A general algebraical determinant in its developed form may be likened to a mixture of liquids seemingly homogeneous, but which, being of differing boiling points, admit of being separated by the process of fractional distillation."

I find it hard to come up with mathematical analogies to reasonably explain the quote (found in Artin's Algebra.)

Comment: I suppose some chemistry knowledge would help you

Comment: Is it possible that he is referring to Laplace's recursive method where a determinant is expressed as a linear combination of the determinants of sub-matrices.

Comment: Ah, that seems reasonable. @nwr

Comment: Outside my area of expertise, thus a comment. The meaning of the quoted text should become clearer by referring to the original publication: J. J. Sylvester, "Note on Determinants and Duadic Disynthemes." *American Journal of Mathematics*, Vol. 2, No. 1, Mar. 1879, pp. 89-96 ([scan online](https://books.google.com/books?id=TOtEH9ASMU0C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false))